# Error on opening Excel file created from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have successfully transformed xml to excel using xslt but when i try to open the file its showing a warning message saying the file is in different format. my header on xslt looks like

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
```

Can anyone please point out the correct method to create excel from xml

Comment: How can you say you have "successfully" transformed it to Excel format when you clearly haven't? And how can you expect us to know where your code is wrong when we can't see your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to import *tabular data*, have your [**XSLT transformation create a CSV file**](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html).

If you require *total control over formulas and formatting*, have your [**XSLT transformation create OOXML**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-using-xslt.aspx).

***Important**: The [**OOXML**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) route is considerably more complex; go with CSV import if at all possible.*

Answer (score 0):

I would be very reluctant to attempt a transformation that creates an Excel spreadsheet from scratch. The format is simply too complex, and debugging the result is too difficult.

What I would be prepared to do is to write a transformation that takes as input (a) an existing Excel spreadsheet, perhaps with recognizable "placeholder" strings in some of the cells, and (b) an XML data document, and which modifies the suppled spreadsheet to put different data in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

When building an Excel file from XSLT the approach I use is

1. Create a sample Excel (a single value in cell A1 will work)
2. Save As "XML Spreadsheet 2003"
3. Open the resultant XML in my XSLT editor and work from there

This has the advantage of giving you all the formatting needed since, as was stated before, the Excel structure can get rather complex. In addition if you have a target look you are going for in Excel the transform into XML Spreadsheet 2003 will keep most of the style so it reduces your overall work.

Once you have it in your editor it's as simple as finding the right cell and dropping in your XSLT statements:

```
<!-- Live -->
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s50796">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@islive = 'true'">
                    <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>No</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
```

Infinitely easier than creating from scratch.